# How to validate a specific type and make my list "type-safe"

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a custom list, that ensures that only one type of reference can be added in my list, i'm trying to make it "type-safe".

The array is already set to an Object type, and everything inherits from Object so how do I substitute/subtype? For example if I want this list to ONLY be able to take String objects. Currently, my program can take both Integer type and String type as seen in the main method.

I can't use generics for this unfortunately.

***MyArrayList***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyArrayList implements MyList {

    private Object[] theList;
    private Object type;

    public MyArrayList() {
        theList = new Object[0];
    }

    public MyArrayList(Object type) {
        theList = new Object[0];
        setType(type);
    }

    public Object getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Object type) {
        if (type == Integer.class || type == String.class || type == Double.class) {
            this.type = type;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid value");
        }
    }

    public boolean add(Object toAdd) {

            if (toAdd != null && toAdd == type.getClass()) {
                Object[] temp = new Object[theList.length + 1];

                for (int index = 0; index < theList.length; index++) {
                    temp[index] = theList[index];
                }
                temp[theList.length] = toAdd;
                theList = temp;
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid type");
                return false;
            }
        }

    public Object get(int index){

        if(index >= 0 && index < theList.length) {

            return theList[index];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public Object remove(int index) {

        if (index >= 0 && index < theList.length) {
            Object[] newList = new Object[theList.length - 1];

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
                if (i == index) {
                    continue;
                }
                newList[j++] = theList[i];
            }
            theList = newList;
            return newList;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public int size(){
        return theList.length;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){

        if(theList.length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        for(Object thing: theList) {

            System.out.print(thing + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

***MyList***

```
/**
 * Write a description of interface List here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public interface MyList
{
    /**
     * Adds a new element at the end of the list.
     * @param the object to add
     * @return true if element successfully added, otherwise false
     */
    boolean add(Object toAdd);

    /**
     * Gets the object at the specified index.
     * @param index value of object to get
     * @return object at that index
     */
    Object get(int index);

    /**
     * Removes specified object from list.
     * @param index value of object to remove
     * @return the object removed
     */
    Object remove(int index);

    /**
     * Returns size of the list
     * @return number of elements in the list
     */
    int size();

    /**
     * @return true if the list has no elements, false otherwise
     */
    boolean isEmpty();

}
```

***Main***

```
import com.sun.jdi.IntegerType;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object list = new Object();
        Object myList = new MyArrayList(list);
        MyArrayList newList = new MyArrayList(myList);


        newList.add(2);
        newList.add("Tom");
        newList.add(0.0);

        newList.display();
```

Comment: “_I can't use generics_”. Why not? If this is a homework, I’d say it’s contrived and pointless. What does it teach you?

Comment: I have to use substitution/subtyping. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Without using generics, you can't achieve compile-time type safety for this. But you can cause an exception to be raised at runtime if you create the array dynamically with a component type that is *not* `java.lang.Object`, with

```
public class MyArrayList implements MyList {

    private Object[] theList;

    public MyArrayList(Class<?> type) {
        this.theList = (Object[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(type, 10);
    }

    ...
```

This way, if the class passed to create the array is `String.class`, then adding an integer to it would result in a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` being thrown, and you can try/catch this exception wherever `this.theList[n] = object` is.

It's worth mentioning, though, that the correct way to do this is to use generics both in your class and in caller classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a self-made double linked list by creating a class that is an element in your list that holds the previous element and the following element of the list. Each of these elements could have one parameter, that is of the specific type you want to safe.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without generics you'll have to do all type-checking yourself, and casting at the call site cannot be avoided.

You could, for example, accept a class Object of the desired type in the constructor, and check that all added Objects are instances of that type:

```
public class MyArrayList implements MyList {

    private Object[] theList;
    private final Class type;

    // I've omitted the generic wildcard here, cause "no generics"
    // Suppress wildcard warnings here if needed
    // never do this in real, post-Java5 code
    public MyArrayList(Class genericType) { 
        //check any preconditions you want on the class
        this.type = genericType;
        this.theList = new Object[0];       
    }

    public void add(Object toAdd) { 
        // omitted code for growing the array here
        this.temp[theList.length] = this.type.cast(toAdd); //throws Exception on type mismatch
    }

}
```

This uses [Class.cast](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) which throws a ClassCastException on mismatch. You could also just use [Class.isInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) to check the tyoe and decide yourself what to do (e.g. throw a different exception).

---

Note that your `setType` would be a bad idea, because once you've got that, you can no longer be sure that the values in the array are actually of that type. You'd have to clear the array when setting the type, which makes the method useless - at that point you can just create a new instance.